# in html, can one a scroll area be nested inside another scroll area?

Tags: javascript, html

for example

```
<div id='outer' style='overflow: scroll' >
  first text
  <div id='inner' style='overflow: scroll'>
    second text
  </div>
  third text
</div>
```

is this correct / will this work?

will `inner` try to stay inside `outer`?

also, if content is added dynamically, is the behavior consistent no matter where it's added?

Comment: Why don't you try it instead of asking if it *will* work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just try?

http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/MXqu8/

Seems it does

Comment: did try and did work, but if not correct and working by accident then I'm in real trouble

Comment: I would not recommend it, but I do not see why it should not work

Answer (score 1):

That would work, though I don't think I've ever seen it used in practice.

Working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/qthjS/

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it's possible. Having a double scrollbar is really bad UX-wise, though.